# Configuring Cypress's Electron browser to handle downloads

Tags: node.js, electron, cypress

Is there a way to configure the Electron browser that is within Cypress, by directly modifying the Electron browser's configuration?

Namely, there's an [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/433) with Cypress where it cannot detect download prompts. However, there's a [solution](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/download-item) that could hypothetically be applied to Electron, which would fix this issue with Cypress.

My thought was to go directly to wherever Electron is being run from within the Cypress library after installing it via npm. However, I cannot find anything pertaining to Electron in my node_modules/, even though Cypress's GitHub repository has mentions of Electron in its [code](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/search?q=electron&unscoped_q=electron).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I know your questions is quiet a bit old but anyway - a solution is in development directly at Cypress:

- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/949#issuecomment-755975882

**Update**: It is available in Cypress >=6.3.0: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/949#issuecomment-763323357

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know that the Cypress team was working on this. It doesn't exactly answer my question, but it's a solution to the more general problem of not being able to download things. +1